How to compute a function parameter such that an asymptotic estimate holds?

Let

$f(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{3}$,
$b(z) := 3x^3+x$,

For some fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$, can we find a $\theta_0$ with $\theta_0 < \lvert \theta \rvert < \pi$ such that
$$f(x \cdot e^{i\theta}) = \mathcal{o}\biggl( \frac{f(x)}{b(x)} \biggr) \quad \text{ for } x \rightarrow \infty \quad ?$$

I do not see how to do this. The part $e^{i\theta}$ reminds me of Eulers' identity and for the $\mathcal{o}$-part the limit criterion might be useful. Could you please help me?
